# get row value listview ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to edit get the values of the clicked row and edit some of the proprieties. I'm new to ASP.net so this is getting very confusing for me.
Here is what I have so far.

**VIEW:**

```
 <table class="table" style=" width: 10px;">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Id usuário
                </th>

                <th>
                    Nome
                </th>

                <th>
                    Salário
                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model.lista_usuario)
            {
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.id_usuario)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(Model =>item.nome_usuario)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.salario)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Selecionar", "usuario_ajuste", new { id = item.id_usuario })
                    </th>
                </tr>
            }
          
        </table>
```

**lista_usuario class**

```
 public class cl_usuario
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public int id_usuario { get; set; }
    public string nome_usuario { get; set; }
    public double salario { get; set; }
    public string tipo_percentual { get; set; }

    public cl_usuario()
    {
      
        id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

}
```

**ajuste_usuario method**

```
 public ActionResult Index(string percentual)
    {
        _usuario.tipo_percentual = string.IsNullOrEmpty(percentual)?string.Empty: percentual;
        if(percentual == "usuario")
        {
            _usuario.lista_usuario = model_home.carrega_usuario();
        }
        return View(_usuario);
    }

    public ActionResult usuario_ajuste(cl_usuario item)
    {
       // cl_usuario usuario = context.cl_usuario.Find(id);
        return View();
    }
```

**carrega_usuario**

```
public static List<cl_usuario> carrega_usuario()
    {
       return  new List<cl_usuario>()
        {
            new cl_usuario(){id_usuario=1,nome_usuario = "Patrícia",salario=666.66},
            new cl_usuario(){id_usuario=2,nome_usuario = "Fernanda",salario=1133.10},
            new cl_usuario(){id_usuario=3,nome_usuario = "Diego",salario=2312.10},
            new cl_usuario(){id_usuario=4,nome_usuario = "Letícia",salario=1111.10},
            new cl_usuario(){id_usuario=5,nome_usuario = "Tiago",salario=1212},
            new cl_usuario(){id_usuario=6,nome_usuario = "Rodnei",salario=1337},
            new cl_usuario(){id_usuario=7,nome_usuario = "Sabrina",salario=9967.50}
        };
    }
```

I wanna be able to click the edit actionlink and get the values of that row.I've created a actionresult called **ajuste_usuario** but my return is always null.

**EDIT**: Added the usuario_ajuste method

Comment: Show your `usuario_ajuste` code. Does it have a GUID parameter called `id`?

Comment: @SteveGreene I edited the question with the method

Answer (score 0):

OK, your parameter name does not match. Try something like this:

```
public ActionResult usuario_ajuste(Guid? id)
{
    // assuming you have an EF context or other database repository
    cl_usuario usario = context.cl_usuarios.Find(id);
    ... now usario will have all the properties
    return View(usario);  // show edit view
}
```

Comment: where this context comes from? I see 2 namespaces when I try to use

Comment: How did you load your table? Did that come from a database?

Comment: I added the method that I use to populate the list

Answer (score 0):

I see that in your HTMl you are using @Html.ActionLink("Selecionar", "usuario_ajuste", new { id = item.id_usuario }) where inside new the name of property is id.

Whereas, In your action method, the expected is usuario.

Please match and correct the names.